# Accessing images on the Fragment Design page from within Adapter

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, interface, adapter

I have a problem. How can I access the images on the Fragment Design page in Adapter.kt
I access the cardView design page and show it in the recyclerView, but I want to write the totals under some lines, so I need to do this data by accessing the fragment design page. but unfortunately I couldn't do it.
can you help

If I do this total line in the CardView design page, it looks like this

This is the error message

Thank you in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANT1s.png)

I am making an application where I write my daily income. I have a row design and a Fragment design page. I show the data I entered in the adapter in the recyclerRow, but at the bottom of this list I have a total line where I collect the columns and I want to write the total of each column in this line, but this last total line is under the recyclerView image on the fragment design page, I tried to access this total line from the adapter, but unfortunately the application crashed every time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBnSK.jpg)

this is the error message I received

I asked many people but I couldn't find an answer, someone told me to use Interface but I couldn't figure out how to use it

Adapter.kt
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxk11.png)

ListFragment.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec2iP.png)